# Function executes before component is updated

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

You can find the [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hodgkin-boen9)

I am very new to react and I find it a bit confusing to put together my first application given the prevalence of different code styles in react.

The purpose of the application is to execute a GraphQL query with a dynamic query based on form input. On first render it should use data provided in  the state. When the user changes the standard value, a new GrapQl should be executed. However, upon trying to change the input value, a new request is released as soon as I press a button and before(!) updating the value.

I have tried different approaches, but none did yield any change.

Here is my code and [application](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hodgkin-boen9)

Since my GraphQL server is running locally, you should expect this return:

```
{
"data": {
    "sensorDataTimeSeriesCurve": [
    {
        "timestamp": "2019-06-12T04:00:00",
        "value": 31.01
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "2019-06-12T05:00:00",
        "value": 33.08
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "2019-06-12T06:00:00",
        "value": 34.28
    }
    ]
}
}
```

src/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider, useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import Chart from "./components/charts/chart";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `https://GRAPHQLENDPOINT`
});

const timeseriesQuery = gql`
  query test0($id1: ID!, $from: DateTime!, $to: DateTime!) {
    sensorDataTimeSeriesCurve(id: $id1, from: $from, to: $to) {
      timestamp
      value
    }
  }
`;

function Timeseries({ id1, from, to }) {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery(
    timeseriesQuery,
    {
      variables: { id1, from, to },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
      // pollInterval: 500
    }
  );

  if (networkStatus === 4) return "Refetching!";
  if (loading) return null;
  if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;
  console.log("Data:", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart data={data.sensorDataTimeSeriesCurve} />
      <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id1: 20742,
      from: "2019-06-12 03:56:13.567",
      to: "2019-06-22 04:56:13.567"
    };
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.id1}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              From:
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.from}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              To:
              <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.to}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
          {this.state.id1 && (
            <Timeseries
              id1={this.state.id1}
              from={this.state.from}
              to={this.state.to}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

src/components/charts/charts.js

```
import { LineChart, Line } from "recharts";
import React from "react";

class Chart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LineChart width={400} height={400} data={this.state.data}>
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="#8884d8" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

My expected behavior is that a new GraphQL request is made after pressing the submit button.

The actual behavior is that right now, as soon as I attemp to change the input fields, a new request is made with the existing input. It is not possible to change the input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is being sent whenever you render the `Timeseries` component, and the `Timeseries` component is being rendered right away (the initial value of you `App` component is truthy).
Another thing is that you don't seem to give your inputs actual names, so how should they know which value to update?

Comment: I understand. It appears my form is setup incorrectly. I wrongly assumed it had different reasons. I will try to fix that. Thank you @Dor Shinar.

Comment: Dor you are of course right, I assumed that react retrieves the key-value relationship automatically, but of course I need to specify the name attribute. The code works now. Thank god it's already Friday. Now I only need to figure out how I can make sure the request only runs after pressing submit.